# Get image from capture and show image in another layout using another activity in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to show image after capture by click button Capture in the FirstActivity and show image in the activity_second(layout) using SecondActivity.

FirstActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    Button take_photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
    take_photo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
}
```

Layout activity_first

```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:text="Capture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SecondActivity

```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view_photo);
    }
```

activity_second

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_photo"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="374dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the menifest I use, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: oh sir, i don't know how to accept cuz i just know how to ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap thumbnail = null;
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", thumbnail);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Next in the next activity try to use this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //intialize the image view 

    Bitmap bitmap  = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("name");
    //set the image here.
}
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: it's does't know this CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST but I try this one 'private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 0;' in the SecondActivity 'view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);' it open the camera and after capture it stay on the FirstActivity not show image in the SecondActivity

Comment: did you use  startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); in the first activity.private final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1; is enough. we need not use static.

Comment: use startActivityforResult(i,somerequestcode) instead of
            startActivity(i);
 The camera application will be started and will go to the onactivityforresult() when we call startActivityforresult()

Comment: I use start     public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
   } but when after capture. application say Unforgettably, Camera has stopped

Comment: Please declare the new Activity in the Manifest File and check again.

Comment: this is project. please you recorrect it. sorry that I trouble u? http://www.mediafire.com/?n2a9o98su6vjdm1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to solve the issues :

Your First Activity:

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        Button take_photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
        take_photo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // start the image capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) 
        {
            Bitmap imageData = null;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
                imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("name", imageData );
                startActivity(i);

            } 
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) 
            {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } 
            else 
            {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
            }
        }
    }
```

and second Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Bitmap bitmap  = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("name");
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view_photo);
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
    }
```

and in Manifest.xml file use the permission:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

I hope this will work fine

Comment: can u answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839042/how-to-make-background-push-up-when-click-edittext-in-android-like-facebook-log

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) 
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                    
    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                       "image" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
    try 
        {                       
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
        } 
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;       
        switch (requestCode) 
            {
                case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                    Bitmap photo =  null;           
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    if (extras != null) 
                    {               
                        photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    }   
                    Intent i =  new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("image", photo);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;  
    }
```

In the second activity:

```
    bMap =  getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Comment: but It's can't save to my sdcard

Answer (score 0):

get the path of the image that you stored and pass it as an extra using intents to other activity in the onActivityResult().
Hope this may help you.

Comment: can u completely my code above? I tried to find solution 2 weeks ago but I can't. can u complete this project? thanks in advance

Comment: did u find the same solution which we suggested?

Comment: Oh Now it's completed, I use @Febi M Felix coding. thanks in advance and sorry for trouble you Sharath G

Comment: one more er... after I capture It's doesn't save to my sdcard.

Comment: yea Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and Emulator using android 4.0.3

Comment: Is your captured image visible in the gallery (in your mobile)?

Comment: if I capture image via native camera in machine it work but in my app it's not work

Comment: does your application save the captured image into the gallery?

Comment: oh I try this code via @Febi M Felix above. how could I do more

Comment: Once try this one     
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
  
  Intent intent = new Intent(
    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  File rootpathfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "hi12334");
rootpathfile.mkdirs(); 
  
  File file = new File(rootpathfile,"abc---"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpeg");
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
  startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

Comment: the captured image might have been stored in the /sdcard/hi12334/abc---systemcurrenttime(when you capture the image)

Comment: When I tick to capture nothing happen and still stay in the camera mod. this is project camera_v2 http://www.mediafire.com/?tur88k2nzue72ca

Comment: Now I add '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />' and it show error in logcat Caused by java.lang.nullPointerException

Comment: can u answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839042/how-to-make-background-push-up-when-click-edittext-in-android-like-facebook-log